# looking for a word in multiple files in directories

Tags: php

I'm working on a searchmachine for my blog (http://iljalicious.net/suche/) and I'm sorry that the used language is not English on the website but I translated the code for you:

```
$lookingfor = $_POST['word'];

$lines = file('../archiv/2015/juli/eintraege.dat');

$found = false;
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    if(strpos($line, $lookingfor) !== false)
    {
        $found = true;
        echo $line;
    }
}
if(!$found)
{
    echo    'I found nothing, dood!';
}
```

Currently, the function is working perfectly, but only if it is looking for a word in one file ('http://iljalicious.net/archiv/2015/juli/eintraege.dat').
On my blog, I have such a file for every month and I want my searchmachine to look for a word in every file called 'eintraege.dat' in the directory '../archiv/' and subdirectories as '2015','2016' etc.

How can I solve this problem?

Greetings, iljalicious

****EDIT*****
Found another..kind of stupid solution:
The code is not translated, but is the same as above, the only thing I changed was:

From:

$lines = file('../archiv/2015/juli/eintraege.dat');

To:

$archiv = file('../suche/archiv.php');

And it worked.

```
$suchbegriff =  $_POST[suchbegriff];

$archiv = file('../suche/archiv.php');

$gefunden =     false;
        foreach($archiv as $zeile)
        {
            if(strpos($zeile, $suchbegriff) !== false)
            {
                $gefunden = true;
                echo $zeile;
            }
        }
        if(!$gefunden)
        {
            echo    '<div class="information">'.
                    'Alter, wonach hast du gesucht?<br>'.
                    'Mhm... Soso, <a>'. $_POST[suchbegriff].
                    '</a> also! '.
                    'Dein Ernst?<br>'.
                    'Als ob ich über sowas berichte O;'.
                    '</div>';
        }
```

Comment: See [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: Do you have a list of all files within your application context (in a variable, file or something else)?

Comment: Btw. pls use single quotes for array keys `$_POST['word']` to avoid notices.

Comment: @LambdaNinja Thank you! But I haven't found out, how I could use scandir for this.
I already tried scandir but without luck.

Comment: @u-nik I have something like this.
http://iljalicious.net/suche/archiv.php <-- This is showing all entries but I haven't found out, how I could connect this  with my code.
EDIT: This includes all files like "../archiv/year/month/eintraege.dat" automatically.

Comment: You grab the dat file over http. Is this the only way you can reach the file? What is about local file access like `file_get_contents('archiv/2015/juli/eintraege.dat')`? Is your script executed on the same host?

Comment: @u-nik Yes, the script is executed on the same host and it should also work like you said, but will it change anything?

Comment: The answer from @nicolò-cozzani may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php),

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern
>   according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is
>   similar to the rules used by common shells.

Something similar to this:

```
$file_list = [];
foreach (glob("archive*/eintraege.dat") as $filename) {
    $file_list[] = $filename;
}
$lookingfor = $_POST['word'];

foreach ($file_list as $file) {
    $lines = $file;

    $found = false;
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $lookingfor) !== false) {
            $found = true;
            echo $line;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        echo 'I found nothing, dood!';
    }
}
```

**Note**: glob work only with files hosted on your server.
So if you want to search from the root of your server, the function argument should be something like : `/var/www/site/content/archieve/*/eintraege.dat`

if you want to search in the same folder of your file:

```
*/eintraege.dat
```

Comment: Thank you!
This looks like it could be what I need, but I already get an error on the first line of code.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' ...
I'm not an expert but I want to understand how all this work.. or dont work.

Comment: wich version of php you use? that is just an empty array declaration. try use $file_list = array();

Comment: Im using PHP v5.3.29 and I tried using what you've said, but I got this: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"(http://iljalicious.net/suche/)

Comment: probably the glob function is returning false, so is impossible to loop.
check if the path of the glob argument is correct.you can prevent error using if statement before the glob. note: dont paste 'path/to' you need to use your real path something like /archiv/* . try reading glob documentation to figure out how it works, and you should be able to easly solve your problem.

Comment: I've checked the path several times, I don't understand why I get this error, the code looks fine to me. Is there a way to to use this file (http://iljalicious.net/suche/archiv.php) for what I want? There are some <?php include '../archiv/20xx/month/eintraege.dat'; ?> inside of that file. ***EDIT: First I will try your edit

Comment: Oh gosh, I guess I have to learn more PHP. Only this way I will understand what I need to do. But thank you for all your help, maybe this will help me a lot more when I understand better how php works.